# unable to call log off method in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I use this code to logout from dropdownmenu but didn't work

```
<li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
```

Here is my Form

```
<form asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">@UserManager.GetUserName(User)! <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Gigs I'm Going</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Artist I'm Following</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javscript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log out</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have a form with Id 'logoutForm' that post to an action that actually logout (remove authentication coockie or something)?

Comment: yeah, can you please post the code having the Id "logoutForm". Mean while you can make use of <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log Out", "LogOff", "Account")</li> for logout functionality

Comment: this is the form

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: This code solve the problem...  

    <li>
        <a onclick="document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit();">Log out</a>
    </li>